# is there a way to skim through a file in C and only print the following lines once a certain string is met? (Beginner)

Tags: c, file-io

I wanted my code to originally read the file line by line, then compare the line with the string I'm searching for. When it matches, I wanted it to start reading and printing lines until I get to an empty line. My current outcome instead only prints the ID number line and nothing else beyond that.

```
 while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    if(strstr(line, ID)!=NULL){
        printf("\n%s", line);
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Is it not obvious that the `printf` is only called when the line contains the ID rather than for every line after it? Basically you need to set a flag rather than have the `printf` inside the condition. Then check the flag to decide whether to print or not.

Comment: You don't need `\n` in your `printf()` since `fgets()` leaves the newline in the `line` string.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing "start reading and printing lines until I get to an empty line"

Comment: BTW, `strstr()` might not be the right test. If you're looking for `ID# 5` that will match `ID# 50`